# AWS EC2 Public Key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, key-pair

I am a first time AWS user, and have been following [this tutorial](https://rubythursday.com/system/episodes/pdfs/000/000/072/original/Ruby_Snack_33_Deploy_to_AWS_E2_Part_3.pdf?1466116468)

to  set up with Ubuntu. I've generated my keys, saved to my computer, and now I'm at a screen that looks like this:

[image]

and the next steps is "put in your key"... I have been searching for hours on the internet, and I can not figure out where to find my key. Am I just pasting in the ssh file I have already saved on my folder, or is there a unique string within that file that I am needing to grab? If so - how do I find that? If not, what am I looking for here? Any help would be appreciated!! Sorry if this is a very elementary question. Thanks!!

Comment: Did you SSH into the instance successfully?

Comment: @error2007s es, I believe so. How would I be able to confirm that? The top of that says '  GNU nano 2.2.6            File: /home/deploy/.ssh/authorized_keys                    Modified  '

Comment: In that procedure what step you are on now?

Comment: @error2007s I just wrote ' nano ~/.ssh/authorized_keys' into my terminal, and it took me to the screen above. then in the tutorial she says "put in your public key" I have no idea what to put in the terminal next..

Comment: Ok what are you using? MAC or Windows?

Comment: @error2007s Mac and I'm doing all of this in my mac's terminal

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/118704/discussion-between-error2007s-and-gwalshington).

Answer (score 1):

Hopefully @error2007s helped but just in case -- you would need to put in your public key that is usually stored in a file called id_rsa.pub in your .ssh folder in your home directory. It starts with ssh-rsa, has a long list of letters and numbers and then ends with the email address you used when creating the key. You can list out the contents of that file by typing this in your terminal:

`cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`

That is what you need to add to the file on your server when you typed ~/.ssh/authorized_keys.  Let me know if you have any other questions!

Comment: I confirmed that I have that file in my .ssh folder, but when i type that whole command, it says `bash: /Users/walshcostigan/.ssh/id_rsa.pub: Permission denied`, when  I type sudo in front of it, it says `command not found`

Comment: I think you are using the $ sign ahead of that don't use that.

Answer (score 0):

To be Direct to your question, on your blank nano editor for authorized_keys, you must put content of id_rsa.pub located under /home/deploy/.ssh/id_rsa.pub. you can simply cat /home/deploy/.ssh/id_rsa.pub, copy entire content and paste on the authorized_keys.

general steps to generate keys are below:

1) ls -ltr /home/deploy/.ssh - you would see like id_rsa, id_rsa.pub and authorized_keys. If you don't have authorized_keys, then do cp id_rsa.pub authorized_keys, it will copy id_rsa.pub content to authorized_keys. Please be sure that .ssh folder has 700 permission and files inside it has 600. Chmod 700 ~/ssh and Chmod 600 ~/ssh/*.

2) Create a key file in your local computer like (nano mydeploykey.pem) and make sure you copy the entire content of id_rsa and paste it on mydeploy.pem. Please ensure -----BEGIN RSA PRIVATE KEY----- contents and -----END RSA PRIVATE KEY----- is present. Note that there are five (5) dashes ----- and make sure you have those in your keys. If you missed copying one dash, it will not work.

Alternatively, you can use winscp or filezilla to copy id_rsa to your local computer and rename it as mydeploykey.pem. this key (mydeploykey.pem) should have 600 permission as well, if its too open, it will complain.

if you are using terminal to login, please use the following command.

ssh -i /path/to/mydeploykey.pem ubuntu@awspublicipaddress. Let me know if this does not work.